# setting text in textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, textarea, greasemonkey

I am trying to process the text in textarea [on Facebook group page. 'write post' has one text area] and replace it with new text. This is done using Greasemonkey script

```
textHolder = document.getElementsByClassName( "uiTextareaAutogrow input mentionsTextarea textInput" )[0];

var vntext=textHolder.value;

var vn2text=Encrypt(vntext);

textHolder.value=vn2text;
```

So new text is seen in text-area but the when the 'post' button is clicked the new text is not  taken instead old text is posted

But if we manually insert at least a character to the processed text then the resulting text is posted after click on post button. So I am not getting why it is directly not taking the new text without inserting the text manually.

There are other events being called in textarea element, but I do not know what they are doing exactly.

So what should be done so that new text will be posted?

DOM for text-area on Facebook page is as follows:

```
<textarea 
    class="uiTextareaAutogrow input mentionsTextarea textInput DOMControl_placeholder" 
    title="Write something..." name="xhpc_message_text" placeholder="Write something..." 
    onfocus="return wait_for_load(this, event, function() {if (!this._has_control) { new TextAreaControl(this).setAutogrow(true); this._has_control = true; } return wait_for_load(this, event, function() {JSCC.get('j4ef51acb72eb241587530255').init(JSCC.get('j4ef51acb72eb241587530256'));;JSCC.get('j4ef51acb72eb241587530256').init(["buildBestAvailableNames","hoistFriends"]);JSCC.get('j4ef51acb72eb241587530253').init({"max":10}, null, JSCC.get('j4ef51acb72eb241587530255'));;;});});" 
    autocomplete="off" style="direction: ltr; "
>
    Write something...
</textarea>
```

Comment: Perhaps all that onfocus garbage is interfering with the post functionality. That much inline JS code is **NEVER** a good idea.

Comment: @MarcB - is inline JavaScript *ever* really a good idea? :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Yes it is, Google does it all the time. But if you're not Google... :)

Comment: @Camilo - ahh, I forgot the first rule of web development .... :)

Comment: It is very likely that Facebook is storing the value of the textarea based on keyup events or similar. So the value isn't read when sending to the server because it's already been stored. Try dispatching a keyup event to the textarea after you modify the value.

Comment: @AdamRackis—inline script is always a good idea if it is better than other ideas for a particular case. It has the benefit of being there as soon as the elements are in the DOM, which is very difficult to achieve any other way. DOMloaded and similar approaches aren't anywhere near as robust.

Answer (score 1):

Can you link to the page in question?

That page could be tracking that textarea's value in JS or even AJAX-posting it with every keystroke.  Clicking the 'post' button might merely tell the page/server to use the last saved version of the text.

Since the GM script changes the textarea value independently of mouse and focus events, the page and/or server tracking mechanism won't be triggered.

So, if you can, find the appropriate JS function and call it after changing the text.

If that's too difficult, try setting the focus to the textarea, then elsewhere and then back to the textarea.

Or try sending a keystroke event to the text area.

Link to the page, or a full-code snapshot of it, for more detailed help.